# Qual è il significato di "avanzare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto questo dialogo:

> – E racconta.
>    
>       – Fascista fino alla punta delle unghie, – continuò
>   Maté. – Era una di quelle che sognavano di fare un figlio
>   con Mussolini. Ed era anche cotta per quel porco di
>   Graziani. 
>       – Un momento, – fece Pinco. – Era giovane, era bella? È importante saperlo subito. 
>       – Era sui trent’anni, – specificò Maté, – ed era una
>   bella pianta di donna. Un po’ robusta, un po’ mascolina,
>   ma ben messa e ben distribuita come carne. E soprattutto aveva una carnagione magnifica, una vera seta. 
>       – Meno male, – disse Pinco, – se era vecchia e brutta
>   potevi **avanzare** di raccontare, anche se fosse il fatto piú
>   interessante del mondo.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "avanzare" nell'ultima frase del brano. Ho letto [questa definizione nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avanzare2/), ma non sono sicura di aver capito il senso in questo contesto. Significa "rispiarmare"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Avanzare", tra le altre cose, ha il significato di "lasciare da parte". In questo caso ne intende una versione un po' distorta che sta per "evitare".

> – Meno male, – disse Pinco, – se era vecchia e brutta potevi *evitare* di raccontare, anche se fosse il fatto piú interessante del mondo.

Comment: Nel libro *L'affaire Moro* di Leonardo Sciascia ho trovato questa frase con il verbo "avenzare" che immagino abbia un senso simile: "Tutti i meccanismi da mettere in moto contro «l’infame ricatto» vengono messi a punto e lubrificati nell’attesa che «l’infame ricatto» ***venga avanzato***."

Comment: @Charo non credo sia lo stesso significato. Nel tuo caso viene usato come "messo in atto": "Tutte le precauzioni contro il ricatto vengono messe a punto nell'attesa che il ricatto venga messo in atto". Avanzare come "portare avanti", "mettere in moto".

Comment: Quindi, si tratta del [significato 1 del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avanzare1/)?

Comment: @Charo quasi, ma figurato. "Come osi avanzare queste calunnie?", "Il tribunale avanzò l'accusa di omicidio nei sui confronti"

Comment: Grazie, @DiegoMartinoia, trovo particolarmente difficile capire questo verbo.

Answer (score 1):

Sono d'accordo con la tua interpretazione di avanzare come "*risparmiare"*. Sorprende l'uso diretto del verbo, che nel linguaggio comune si trova piú spesso nella forma riflessiva *"risparmiarsi"*.

Il [Tommaseo-Bellini](http://www.tommaseobellini.it/#/items) dà come primo significato di avanzare

```
V. a. Da AVANZO. Mettere in avanzo, Acquistare, Accumulare. T. Differisce da 
Restare, perchè in quello è l'idea di cosa che resta oltre all'adoprato o al 
necessario. Prov. Tosc. 270. Chi digiuna, e altro ben non fa, Avanza il pane, 
e a casa il diavol va. = Bocc. Nov. 13. 6. (C) In pochi anni grandissima 
quantità di danari avanzarono. [Cam.] G. B. Gell. 184. Tu avanzavi ogni anno 
buona quantità di danari.
```

In questo senso Maté *"risparmierebbe tempo e fiato"* a non raccontare il resto della storia se la donna in questione fosse brutta. C'è una sfumatura di significato che ritengo intenzionale: il *risparmio* non sarebbe stato solo a vantaggio di Maté e quindi un vantaggio, riflessivo, per lui stesso. Ma anche un vantaggio per Pinco che non dovrebbe ascoltare.